# VC++ Inline assembly errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I have been searching around for a while, and couldn't seem to find the answer to my issue. I'm trying to code some functions to detect whether or not the executable is being debugged, and I'm using some inline assembly for it (with the __asm tag). It keeps throwing two errors, and the rest of the code seems to compile fine. Here's the function

```
int peb_detect() {
     __asm {
         ASSUME FS : NOTHING
         MOV EAX, DWORD PTR FS : [18]
         MOV EAX, DBYTE PTR DS : [EAX + 30]
         MOVZX EAX, BYTE PTR DS : [EAX + 2]
         RET
     }
}
```

and I keep getting the errors

```
warning C4405: 'FS': identifier is reserved word
warning C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'FS'
warning C2408: illegal type on PTR operator in 'second operand'
```

I can't seem to figure it out. If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear which lines the errors refer to, but I guess you should delete the whole `assume` line, and you have a typo `DBYTE`.

Comment: What's wrong with `IsDebuggerPresent`?

Comment: @Jester where is the typo?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm several reasons, one being that I obsessive compulsively re-invent the wheel on everything I see (kidding) and also, I heard that 'IsDebuggerPresent' can be bypassed easily.

Comment: Typo: I believe he is referring to `DBYTE`.  I've heard of `DWORD` and I've heard of `BYTE`.  Not sure what `DBYTE` might be.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd well I put DBYTE and that replaced it but now I'm getting the error "illegal type on PTR operator in second operand", so I'm a bit frustrated with the recursive errors.

Comment: The `DBYTE` should be `DWORD`.

Comment: @user7423208 - "IsDebuggerPresent' can be bypassed easily". Assuming the program will run in windows which allows both local and remote debugging (possibly via a modified device driver or debugging kernel), it's difficult to prevent a hack, as the first step is usually to disable any checks similar to "IsDebuggerPresent". The main issue is if a program (like a game) is popular enough to attract hackers. At least such a check will usually prevent casual users from using a trainer.

Comment: *"Did you debug it?!"* (sorry, couldn't resist the pun joke)

Comment: @Ped7g hah hah hah.

Answer (score 0):

at first not 18 but 0x18 and not 30 but 0x30

```
C_ASSERT(FIELD_OFFSET(NT_TIB, Self) == 0x18);
C_ASSERT(FIELD_OFFSET(TEB, ProcessEnvironmentBlock) == 0x30);
```

need use not hard coded constants. especially wrong.

at second `int peb_detect()` must be `__declspec(naked)` if you use `RET` instruction. so code can look like this:

```
#include <winternl.h>
#include <intrin.h>

__declspec(naked) BOOLEAN peb_detect() {
    __asm {
        MOV EAX, FS:[NT_TIB.Self]
        MOV EAX, [EAX + TEB.ProcessEnvironmentBlock]
        MOV AL, [EAX + PEB.BeingDebugged]
        RET
    }
}
```

but we can use and shorter variant

```
__declspec(naked) BOOLEAN peb_detect2() {
    __asm {
        MOV EAX, FS:[TEB.ProcessEnvironmentBlock]
        MOV AL, [EAX]PEB.BeingDebugged
        RET
    }
}
```

and for implement `IsDebuggerPresent` we can not use inline assembler at all. and this will be work for x64 too

```
__forceinline BOOLEAN peb_detect3()
{
    return ((PEB*)
#ifdef _WIN64
        __readgsqword
#else
        __readfsdword
#endif
        (FIELD_OFFSET(_TEB, ProcessEnvironmentBlock)))->BeingDebugged;
}
```

Comment: @user7423208 - sorry for my English, what is unclear ?

Comment: 'ProcessEnviromentBlock': illegal struct/union member in 'second operand' @RbMm

Comment: @user7423208 are you `#include <winternl.h>` ?

Comment: note: this error is under the instruction: MOV EAX, [EAX + TEB.ProcessEnviromentBlock] and I am including it in "stdafx.h". Should I include it directly in the .cpp file?

Comment: @user7423208 - are you have definition for `TEB` and `PEB` in code ?

Comment: @user7423208 - say `peb_detect3()` is compiled ?

Comment: `C_ASSERT(FIELD_OFFSET(TEB, ProcessEnvironmentBlock) == 0x30);` gives the error "Class _TEB has no member ProcessEnviromentBlock", and I'm not entirely sure how to define PEB

Comment: @user7423208 - are you read in my answer and comment about `#include <winternl.h>` ? or use own definition for TEB , PEB. `I'm not entirely sure how to define PEB` - if so, why you try access it direct ?!? and if so hard - use hardcoded 0x18, 0x30, 0x2